# R - creating a variable that records categorical info of other member of a group

Tags: r, dataframe, categorical-data, tapply

I have a dataset `data` of families, with every household identified by a variable `id` and every person identified with `id + num` (id of family + person of the family). For every person I have various demographic characteristics, like this:

```
id  num  age  wage     edu            marital_status
1   1    33   1200    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating
1   2    35   1100    College         Married/Cohabitating
1   3    12   -1      Not applicable  Not applicable
2   1    27   1600    College         Single
3   1    59   2000    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating
3   2    51   1800    Other           Married/Cohabitating
```

I have created a set of variables that record the characteristics of another member of the household.
So, for example, I wanted to have a variable for 'wage of partner' `wage_p` for households with two married or cohabitating adults, which I obtained with

```
sums = tapply(data$wage, data$id, sum)
data$wage_tot = sums[match(data$id,names(sums))]
data$wage_tot[!(data$id %in% data$id[duplicated(data$id)])] = NA
data$wage_p = data$wage_tot - data$wage
```

Basically, I summed `wage` per household obtaining `wage_tot` and then subtracted `wage` to obtain `wage_p.`

Which worked because I first restricted the dataset to married or cohabitating individuals (so I had 1 or 2 individuals per household).
(I know this is probably more convoluted than necessary).

My results:

```
id  num  age  wage     edu            marital_status        wage_tot   wage_p
1   1    33   1200    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating   2300      1100
1   2    35   1100    College         Married/Cohabitating   2300      1200
2   1    27   1600    College         Single                 NA         NA
3   1    59   2000    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating   3800      1800
3   2    51   1800    Other           Married/Cohabitating   3800      2000
```

Now the problem comes when I want to do this with categorical variables, because I cannot get a total and then subtract like I did with the continuous variables.
So for example, if I want to create a variable that records the level of education of the spouse, `edu_p`.

```
id  num  age  wage     edu            marital_status         edu_p
1   1    33   1200    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating   College
1   2    35   1100    College         Married/Cohabitating   Secondary
2   1    27   1600    College         Single                 NA
3   1    59   2000    Secondary       Married/Cohabitating   Other
3   2    51   1800    Other           Married/Cohabitating   Secondary
```

The only idea that I could come up with would be to transform the categorical variable in numeric, use my method, and then transform them again but i'm sure it is waay more complicated that it has to be.

Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Could you `dput(data)` and paste that into your question? It's much easier to help you if we have a sample of your data. Also, if you could post a sample of what your desired output looks like, that would be helpful as well. Read more about providing a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @BenNorris Thank you so much! I am going to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a `merge` solution to compare each couple against each other using `id`. Final left join `merge` used to include not couple observations from original data.

```
spouse_merge <- subset(merge(data, data, by="id", suffixes=c("", "_p")),
                       (num < num_p | num > num_p) & 
                       marital_status != "Not applicable" &
                       marital_status_p != "Not applicable")

final_df <- merge(data, spouse_merge[c(1,2, grep("_p", names(spouse_merge)))], 
                  by=c("id", "num"), all.x=TRUE)
final_df
```

<kbd>[**Online Demo**](https://rextester.com/IQZL27738)</kbd>